# How to change certain aesthetics of facet_grid ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-visualization, facet-grid

I created this plot using `facet_grid` and `patchwork` because I needed to have a customized secondary y-axis for each of the parameter and they all have different scale. I have successfully tweaked most of the aesthetics to match with what I need for the graph except for a couple of places:

[image: Plot]

1. Matching color with "site." I would like to match red, blue, and green to Port, Bluff, and Palm respectively. It didn't work with the code I have in `scale_color_manual`.
2. Renaming the strip text. I tried using `expression(paste())` before but it wasn't working, especially with greek letter. I would like to have these respective stip text on the right for each row: ETR[max], ɑ, and E[k]. 
   Letter in the [] are subscripts.

Thank you for any pointers. I ran out of things to try to make this week, especially with the strip texts.

My dataframe: [data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L3KEmXIt04wGQvzy7xAmgxdcp-DPZlFO/view?usp=sharing)

My codes are:

```
abrv_mo <- with (params, month.abb[month]) params <- transform(params, month = abrv_mo) params <- params[order(match(params$month, month.abb)), ] params$month <- factor(params$month, month.abb, ordered = TRUE) params$month<- as.Date(ISOdate(2019, as.numeric(params$month), 15))

p1 <- ggplot() +   geom_hline(yintercept = 19.6, linetype = "dashed")
+   geom_line(data = tmpr2, 
            aes(month, tmp*0.98), 
            alpha = 0.4) +   geom_errorbar(data = subset(params, variable == "max"),
                aes(x= month, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean +se, color = site),
                width = 8) +   geom_point(data = subset(params, variable == "max"), 
             aes(x=month, y=mean, color = site, group=site),
             size = 2.5) +   facet_grid(rows = vars(variable),
             cols = vars(site),
             switch = "y", scale = "free_y") +   scale_x_date(name = NULL, date_labels = "%b", 
               seq(as.Date("2019-01-15"), 
                   as.Date("2019-07-15"), by = "1 month")) + # ?strftime() for more options   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(5,40), breaks = seq(5, 40, by = 15),
                     expand = c(0,0), 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./0.98)) +   scale_color_manual(name = "Site",
                    labels = c("Port", "Bluff", "Palm"),
                    values = c("#FC4E07","#00AFBB", "#C3D7A4")) +   theme_bw() +   theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(size=1, colour = "black"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"),
        axis.line = element_line(size=0.1, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(size=0.5, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, color="black", margin = margin(t = 0.5, l = 0.5)),
        text = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.position="none",
        plot.margin=margin(l = -1, unit = "cm")) +   ylab(NULL)  

p2 <- ggplot() +   geom_hline(yintercept = 0.16, linetype = "dashed")
+   geom_line(data = tmpr2, 
            aes(month, tmp*0.008),
            alpha = 0.4) +   geom_errorbar(data = subset(params, variable=="slope"),
                aes(x= month, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean +se, color = site),
                width = 8) +   geom_point(data = subset(params, variable == "slope"), 
             aes(x=month, y=mean, color=site, group=site),
             size = 2.5) +   facet_grid(rows = vars(variable),
             cols = vars(site),
             switch = "y",
             scale = "free_y") +   scale_x_date(name = NULL, date_labels = "%b", 
               seq(as.Date("2019-01-15"), 
                   as.Date("2019-07-15"), by = "1 month")) + # ?strftime() for more options   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.15,
0.26, by = 0.05),
                     expand = c(0,0), 
                     limits = c(0.15,0.26),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./0.008, name = "Temperature (°C)")) +   scale_color_manual(name = "Site",
                     labels = c("Port", "Bluff", "Palm"),
                     values = c("#FC4E07","#00AFBB", "#C3D7A4")) +   theme_bw() +   theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(size=1, colour = "black"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"),
        axis.line = element_line(size=0.1, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(size=0.5, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, color="black", margin = margin(t = 0.5, l = 0.5)),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(size=10, color="black", margin = margin(t = 0.5, r = 10)),
        text = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.position="none",
        plot.margin=margin(l = -1.5, unit = "cm")) +   ylab(NULL)  

p3 <- ggplot() +   geom_hline(yintercept = 140, linetype = "dashed") + geom_line(data = tmpr2, 
            aes(month, tmp*7),
            alpha = 0.4) +   geom_errorbar(data = subset(params, variable=="ek"),
                aes(x= month, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean +se, color = site),
                width = 8) +   geom_point(data = subset(params, variable=="ek"), 
             aes(x=month, y=mean, color=site, group=site),
             size = 2.5) +   facet_grid(rows = vars(variable),
             cols = vars(site),
             switch = "y",
             scale = "free_y") +   scale_x_date(name = NULL, date_labels = "%b", 
               seq(as.Date("2019-01-15"), 
                   as.Date("2019-07-15"), by = "1 month")) + # ?strftime() for more options   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), 
                     breaks = seq(25, 250, by = 100),
                     limits = c(25,250),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./7)) +   scale_color_manual(name = "Site",
                     labels = c("Port", "Bluff", "Palm"),
                     values = c("#FC4E07","#00AFBB", "#C3D7A4")) +   theme_bw() +   theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(size=1, colour = "black"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"),
        axis.line = element_line(size=0.1, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(size=0.5, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,size=10, color="black", hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0.5, r = 0.5)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, color="black", margin = margin(t = 0.5, l = 0.5)),
        text = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.position="none",
        plot.margin=margin(l = -1.5, unit = "cm")) +   ylab(NULL) 

library(patchwork) 
p1 + p2 + p3 +   plot_layout(ncol = 1)
```

Comment: For your colors in `scale_color_manual`, you need to use the `breaks` argument. `labels` will re-label your plot. You want `scale_color_manual(name = "Site", levels = c("Port", "Bluff", "Palm"), values = c("#FC4E07","#00AFBB", "#C3D7A4"))` (assuming "Port", "Bluff", and "Palm") are the factor levels in your data---I didn't download to check).

Comment: As far as the strip text - it's a small problem with a label. I think you'll likely get help much faster if you create a **minimal** reproducible example. One that doesn't ask people to download a file, put it in their working directory, load it into R, convert date columns, etc. If you either (a) use a built-in dataset or (b) come up with a ~20 line sample data set that we can copy/paste (either share simulation code or use `dput()` to copy the object), you will make it much easier for people to help you. And it makes the question a better resource in case your drive link ever goes dead.